# Persistent connection not working between the squid (version 4.13) and Apache (origin server)

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, squid

I would be very happy if somebody could help.

I am basically trying to make the connection between the Squid (version 4.13) proxy and the Apache server (origin) persistent. I've tried the persistent_server_connections and many other directive value combinations. None of them has worked. Here is my squid configuration:

```
http_port 80 accel defaultsite=127.0.0.1
cache_peer 127.0.0.1 parent 8080 0 proxy-only originserver
http_access allow all
```

I've done some debugging using tcpdump to confirm that it is the Squid proxy closing the connection, not the origin server. In fact, when I replace Apache with some other origin server (say ATS), the connection is still not persistent. But when I replace squid with another proxy (say varnish) the connection between the proxy and the origin server is persistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to make the connection between the squid proxy and the origin server persistent. I just added two lines to my config. The config below works. Also, I got these two lines from this [thread](http://squid-web-proxy-cache.1019090.n4.nabble.com/Fwd-Squid-Keepalive-connections-issue-td4685329.html).

```
http_port 80 accel defaultsite=127.0.0.1
cache_peer 127.0.0.1 parent 8080 0 proxy-only originserver
http_access allow all
acl post_req method POST PUT
server_pconn_for_nonretriable allow post_req
```